# AP2127 Shutdown pin

Tags: power

How does the shutdown pin of the [AP2127](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2127.pdf)  work?
If i pull the shutdown pin to vin, will the output be enabled? Or is it the other way around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that there's a bar above the "SHUTDOWN" means that it's inverted. I.e. "shutdown" is active when low.

If you thus pull it high, then shutdown will be disabled, and your chip will be active.